# Name of a German Novel about a Girl Stalking a Man

Tags: identification-request, german-language

I'm looking for a German novel which centers around a girl stalking a man. The man ends up fighting in World War I and even then the girl follows him into the trenches. I think her motive was unrequited love, and they were both German themselves, but I'm not too sure about those things. I think it was written not too long after World War 1 itself, definitely last century. Unfortunately I don't recall much more than that. Any help is appreciated.